# Using Material Design Icons in Flutter Projects

Tags: flutter

Due to the lack of icons in the classic material icon pack I'd like to use the Material Design Icons.

As for the `pubspec.yaml` I added the following dependancy:

```
material_design_icons_flutter: 3.4.4595
```

As an output I'm getting:

```
[project] flutter packages get
Running "flutter pub get" in project...                            0,5s
```

The package is imported as well:

```
import 'package:material_design_icons_flutter/material_design_icons_flutter.dart';
```

when using the icons it actually offers me the icons from the package:

```
  floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
    child: Icon(MdiIcons.fileAccount),
    backgroundColor: Colors.blueAccent,
    onPressed: () {},
  ),
```

[image]

However, when reloading the app, I get an missing Icon error:

[image]

Thankful for any hints to get Material Design icons working here.

Comment: working perfectly fine.

Comment: @JayMungara Have you tried using it? For some reason I am not able to get any Icon to show up from the MDI Package. Do I have to do something else to get this up and running? It's basically all I did as I wrote it here.

Comment: Yes, i've tried and it's working.

Comment: I have the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

I have tried the plugin and working as intended.

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Text("Hello"),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        child: Icon(MdiIcons.fileAccount),
        backgroundColor: Colors.blueAccent,
        onPressed: () {},
      ),
    );
  }
```

In the pubspec.yaml file

```
material_design_icons_flutter: ^3.4.4595
```

Comment: That's exactly what the question has, save the for the '^'.

Answer (score 1):

i have same problem but i solved

make sure

1. you must install material design icon
2. if you had install close your emulator

Comment: Please, provide a more specific instructions to your response.

Answer (score 0):

I was also getting the "missing icon" error symbol after adding the material_design_icons_flutter package as a dependency to pubspec.yaml.  Once I restarted my emulator the "missing icon" symbol went away and the icons displayed correctly.

Comment: unfortunately restarting the emulator didn't solve my issue. I ended up using other icons because I was unable to get them to work. Since there were a couple of flutter updates since my post the issue may not even exist anymore.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error. For me, a hot reload was not enough to get the icons working. However, restarting the main script and rebuilding the app on the emulator solved it for me.

Answer (score -1):

This worked for me.
Just do

1. flutter clean
2. flutter run

This properly installs the package and icons pack too. And it will solve the problem.